Get difference in values of second table from IDs in two columns of first table?
Given these two tables:
Table1



id1
id2




224
2341


5234
9394


6243
2342


⋮
⋮



Table2



id
value




224
2


2341
52


2342
24


5234
23


6243
242


9394
99


⋮
⋮



I would like to create this table:
Table3



id1
id2
diff




224
2341
52-2


5234
9394
99-23


6243
2342
24-242


⋮
⋮
⋮



where diff = (value of id2) - (value of id1).
I tried doing this with multiple nested sub-queries with joins, but it seemed quite a belabored/kludgy way of doing it. What is the simplest way of doing this?

Two aliased joins.

@user1937198 I'm not familiar with aliasing. Please type up an answer. Thanks.

You need to join table2 twice
SELECT x.id, y.id, y.value - x.value
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 x
    ON t1.id1 = x.id
JOIN table2 y
    ON t1.id2 = y.id

Regarding the comment you got "Two aliased joins", you temporarily rename the tables so they can be distinguished. In my example, I used:
JOIN table2 x

which means that this instance of table2 can be referred to as x. You can use "AS" for clarity if you wish:
JOIN table2 AS x

I typically use aliases for all tables (even when not necessary) and qualify all attributes with the aliases. It makes it easier to understand where the attribute origins from.
